# how to solve unexpected end with concatenation

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate some cells for customers reports, I know the formula works manually as I have used it many times, but when it comes to putting it into a VBA to automate it as much as possible, I get a compile error: Expected: End of Statement.

The Syntax is:

```
Range("E8").Value = "=CONCATENATE(E6," ", TEXT(E7,"#,##0.00"))
```

I get the error message in the part `",text(E7,"`

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

I've tried adding additional `"` where I think they could be missing,

Comment: If you want to use quotation marks in a string you need to use doubled quotes: `Range("E8").Value = "=CONCATENATE(E6,"" "", TEXT(E7,""#,##0.00""))"`. However, I think you should use `.Formula` instead of `.Value`

Comment: Oh my days!! it was that simple!! Thank you so much Gowire, that has resolved the issue! Thank you!